# Webflux not propagating exception when Schedulers.elastic in Springboot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, exception, spring-webflux

I'm facing an issue when trying to handle exceptions on Springboot when using webflux.
I have implemented a ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class, which is working fine, however, if an exception is thrown from a WebFlux thread then it is never called (although if using Schedulers.immediate(), in this case the exception handler is called as well).
The easiest way to replicate that issue I found is by executing:

```
Mono.fromCallable(() -> {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    })
    .doOnError(throwable -> {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    })
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.elastic())
    .subscribe(result -> {}, throwable -> {throw new IllegalArgumentException();});
```

As I said, if instead of using Schedulers.elastic() I use Schedulers.immediate(), then I can handle the exception on my ResponseEntityExceptionHandler class. How could I propagate the exception so I can always handle it on my handler class?

Thanks in advance

Comment: So you `subscribe()` to the `Publisher` with no exception handling and wonder why your exception isn't handled? What did you expect? Either 1) give the `Publisher` to Spring like you are supposed to or 2) add an error handler to manually handle the error.

Comment: I've updated the code with a doOnError; I'd like to propagate the error outside the subscription. Even if i throw an exception from error's callback in subscribe method, that exception is not being propagated

Comment: Sorry. I really don't understand the question. Reactor is asynchronous and you're not handling errors so how do you expect them to be handled? Your subscription doesn't have an error callback so it's being ignored.

Comment: As a general rule, calling `subscribe()` is a Bad Idea - especially in WebFlux. You should return the `Publisher` to Spring to handle it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately, the springboot version I'm using do not understand about WebFlux; so I have to create a DeferredResult which is updated on subscription, so I have to handle by myself.

Comment: Then it's not WebFlux, it's just Reactor surely. I would concentrate on upgrading Spring Boot and not on trying to reinvent the wheel. Concurrency is hard, reactive programming is harder. It doesn't seem to me like you have enough knowledge to implement all the required corner cases correctly.

Comment: Not least because you keep rethrowing your exception rather than handling it - that's not how asynchronous programming works - there is no "outer scope" to which the exception will propagate - it will just unwind the stack on the background thread and be lost. You seem to be trying to propagate the exception to the thread that calls `subscribe()` by rethrowing it, but this thread may well have moved on to other things or simply exited. `subscribe()` isn't a blocking operation, it's **asynchronous** - as you asked it to be when you scheduled work on background threads.

Comment: And don't even get me started on the complexities of correctly handling cancellation...

Comment: You are right, I've got it working by calling deferredresult's setErrorResult method and Spring handles it. Thank you very much

Comment: @FVod could you turn that discussion into an answer please?

Comment: @BoristheSpider You said manual `subscribe()` is a bad idea in Webflux. Can you explain it a little bit more please? -- 

Q1. I thought `subscribe()` is what is called 'fire-and forgot`, which means that I will not care the result from main thread, outer scope or whatever. Am I right? and Is it ok to use it in this assumption? --

Q2. I felt like you recommend returning every Mono/Flux to Spring Framework (e.g., ServerResponse?) instead of solving manually. If I'm right, Why should I? What is the differences between manual subscription and Spring handling?

Comment: 1) yes. But fire and forget is nontrivial. It’s rare you have tasks you actually don’t care about the result of. 2) needs more context. I said you should return the publisher to the controller method as Spring needs to handle the subscription and error handling - this is literally what WebFlux is; handling of publishers in controller methods. Not, what you imply, which is somehow returning every publisher to Spring. 3) comments are not for extended discussion; post a question if you have a question - I won’t respond further.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally let Spring handle the exceptions (through ExceptionHandler) so, in my controller I set response as:

```
final DeferredResult<ResponseDTO> result = new DeferredResult<>();
Mono.fromCallable(...).subscribe(result::setResult, result::setErrorResult);
```